# Use of undeclared type 'FirebaseAuthCrential'

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am following a video tutorial where i am going to do facebook authentication.

I have done the exact same thing as the guy in the video, but he doesn't get any error.

The problem is when i am going to use FirebaseFacebookProvider and FirebaseAuthCredential.

I have installed all the pods and imported them.

This is my code.

```
import UIKit
import FBSDKCoreKit
import FBSDKLoginKit
import Firebase

class LoginViewController: UIViewController{

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    @IBAction func facebookBtnTapped(_ sender: AnyObject) {

        let facebookLogin = FBSDKLoginManager()

        facebookLogin.logIn(withReadPermissions: ["email"], from: self) { (result, error ) in
            if error != nil {
                print("JESS: Unable to authenticate with facebook - \(error)")
            }else if result?.isCancelled == true{
                print("JESS: User cancelled facebook authentication")
            }else {
                print("JESS: Successfully authenticated with facebook")
                let credential = FirebaseFacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: FBSDKAccessToken.current().tokenString)
                self.firebaseAuth(credential)
            }
        }

    }

    func firebaseAuth(_ credential: FirebaseAuthCrential){
        FirebaseAuth.auth()?.signIn(with: credential, completion: { (user, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("JESS: Unable to authenticate with facebook - \(error)")
            }else {
                print("JESS: Sucessfully authenticated with Firebase")
            }
        })

    }
```

Comment: Where is the error?

Comment: I get the error in the first line of this


func firebaseAuth(_ credential: FirebaseAuthCrential){
        FirebaseAuth.auth()?.signIn(with: credential, completion: { (user, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("JESS: Unable to authenticate with facebook - \(error)")
            }else {
                print("JESS: Sucessfully authenticated with Firebase")
            }
        })

Answer (score 1):

You have `FirebaseAuthCrential` but it should be `FirebaseAuthCredential`.

Comment: in Swift - FirebaseAuthCredential